# Mock testing a post method which returns the location of the newly added entity and a 201 status code, using ServletUriComponentsBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, testing, junit, mockito

```
@PostMapping(path= "/users/{username}/events")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createEventsForUser(@PathVariable String username, @RequestBody @Valid EventBean event){
        event.setUsername(username);
        EventBean savedEvent = eventJPAService.save(event);
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
.fromCurrentRequest()
.path("/{eventId}")
.buildAndExpand(savedEvent.getEventId())
.toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
```

this is the code of the post method that i want to test using Junit and mockito. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
@Test
    public void testCreateEventsForUser() {
        String username = "testuser";
        EventBean newEvent = new EventBean(404, "testuser","New Event", "Planning", LocalDate.now());
        int expectedEventId = 404;

        // Mock the behavior of eventJPAService.save
        when(eventJPAService.save(newEvent)).thenReturn(new EventBean(expectedEventId,"testuser" ,"New Event", "Planning", LocalDate.now());

        ResponseEntity<Object> response = eventController.createEventsForUser(username, newEvent);

        // Verify the response status and location
        assertEquals(201, response.getStatusCodeValue());
        URI location = response.getHeaders().getLocation();
        assertEquals("/users/testuser/events/404", location.getPath());
    }
```

getting error:
No current ServletRequestAttributes

Answer (score 1):

To resolve an issue, you can create a mock `HttpServletRequest` and set it as the current request attribute using `RequestContextHolder`, So the test case would be like this (I also updated deprecated stuff for checking statusCode):

```
  @Test
  public void testCreateEventsForUser() {
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    request.setRequestURI("/users/testuser/events");
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));
    
    String username = "testuser";
    EventBean newEvent = new EventBean(404, "testuser","New Event", "Planning", LocalDate.now());
    int expectedEventId = 404;

    // Mock the behavior of eventJPAService.save
    when(eventJPAService.save(newEvent)).thenReturn(new EventBean(expectedEventId,"testuser" ,"New Event", "Planning", LocalDate.now());

    ResponseEntity<Object> response = eventController.createEventsForUser(username, newEvent);

    // Verify the response status and location
    assertEquals(201, response.getStatusCode().value());
    URI location = response.getHeaders().getLocation();
    assertNotNull(location);
    assertEquals("/users/testuser/events/404", location.getPath());
  }
```